# MySQL optimizing tips for the ABS calculation

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have the MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tableexample` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `val0` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val1` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val2` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val3` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val4` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val5` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    .................
    `val1996` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val1997` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val1998` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `val1999` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
) ENGINE=MEMORY ;
```

And this query where can be up to 500 fields:

```
SELECT
  ( ABS(`val1`-12)
  + ABS(`val22`-22)
  + ABS(`val23`-3)
  + ABS(`val45`-87)
  + ABS(`val76`-23)
    ........
  + ABS(`val1324`-7)
  + ABS(`val1576`-29)
  ) as valcal,
  id
FROM `tableexample`
ORDER BY valcal ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Also the numbers from `ABS` are unique for every query (12, 22, 3, 87, 23, 7, 29, ...) and can be in range 0-99.

I made some tests:

```
for 1000 records the sql run in 0.024 seconds
for 10000 records the sql run in 0.231 seconds
for 50000 records the sql run in 1.123 seconds
for 100000 records the sql run in 2.179 seconds
for 200000 records the sql run in 4.316 seconds
for 300000 records the sql run in 6.451 seconds
```

Do you have any optimizing tips, because there are around 300,000 records in database?

Comment: my tip would be to renormalize this thing.. yipes

Comment: If this performance isn't acceptable, I think you'll need to re-evaluate your design, because I don't think you'll get any gains from trying to optimize `abs`.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify/create tables/indexes? Is it some kind of nearest neighbour algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I can modify/create tables/indexes. Do you have any tip? Alex

Answer (score 0):

This query will always have to run through all 300,000 records and perform 500 calculations per record. It's roughly doing 23M calculations a second which isn't bad. The only way to optimize this is better hardware, but even then its hard.

Adding an index won't help. The only way it can help is to rethink your structure or logic completely.